# trouble in getViewTypeCount & getItemViewType methods

Tags: android, android-listview, admob, baseadapter

I wish to insert an ads on top of the listview, however from the example provided by the admob it use `BaseAdapter` in the constructor while mine I used `ArrayList<Hashmap>` hence I am very confuse at the moment please help me out.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements AdListener{

private static String admobId = null;
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public ListAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    this.activity = a;
    this.data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size()+1; //Adding one ads
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (isItemAnAd(position)) {
        return null;
    }
    return data.get(getOffsetPosition(position));
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;

    if (isItemAnAd(position)) {
          if (vi instanceof AdView) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "I am reusing an ad");
            return vi;
          } else {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "I am creating a new ad");
            AdView adView = new AdView(activity, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, getAdmobId(activity));
            AdRequest adRequestBanner = new AdRequest();
            adView.loadAd(adRequestBanner);
            return adView;
          }
    } else {

    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
    TextView subject = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.subject);
    TextView permalink = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.permalink);

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map = data.get(position);
     //Setting all values in listview

       subject.setText(map.get(ViewPagerAdapter.KEY_NEWS_SUBJECT));
       permalink.setText(map.get(ViewPagerAdapter.KEY_NEWS_PERMA));

    return vi;
        }
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
 //what should i write here?
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
 //what should i write here?
}

//Ads
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
  return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
  return (!isItemAnAd(position));
}

private boolean isItemAnAd(int position) {
  // Place an ad at the first 
  return (position == 0);
}

private int getOffsetPosition(int position) {
  return position - 1;
}
}
```

What way I should write on `getViewTypeCount()` & `getItemViewType()`.

Update:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isItemAnAd(position)) {
          return 0;
        } else {
          return 1;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You list view has 2 kinds of rows: ad and normal row. So `getViewTypeCount` should return 2. Let's give ad row type 0, and normal row type 1. Than `getItemViewType` should return 0 if `isItemAnAd` is true and 1 otherwise.

Comment: Hi Nikita, I had followed ur method, however there is a little issue. The ads take over the first listview item and cause IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 13, size is 13
? What are the cause?

Comment: Ah, the problem is when you're in `getView` method and position is 1 it means you need to get first item from data so you should use your `getOffsetPosition` instead just `position` in this line: `map = data.get(position);`

Comment: Thanks alot Nikita !! It works now. By the way just asking, If i wanted to make one item in the listview to be different from the rest, i use similar method? The getviewtypecount() become 3?

Comment: for example like on the every 4th item the in the listview layout show Image Banner only which are difference from the rest tat have text.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov : Why would one implement the `getItemViewType()` although this was already done in the `getView()` when calling the `if (isItemAnAd(position)) {` statement, both will do the same thing I think, so, why call another method here.